# What's the name for the people in red in Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

I'm watching *Star Wars VI : Return of the Jedi* on television. Approximately forty minutes into the movie, Lord Vader lands for the second time on a spaceship. Some beings wearing totally red clothing are waiting to greet him. What are these beings called? I'd never seen them before in *Star Wars*.

Comment: Red persons, LOL!

Comment: How would you call it?

Comment: No, the title was funny before I read the question. ;)

Comment: By the way, I think the person landing and being received by the royal guard was in fact the Emperor, not Vader.

Comment: @bitmask Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's the [Emperor's Royal Guard](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Royal_Guard).

[image: Royal Guard in one of the old films]

Comment: Are you sure, it may be Darth Maul. ;)

Comment: @Eve: Darth Maul is kind of red-black-ish ;)

Comment: @Eve I know Darth Maul, last year I went to carnival as Darth Maul.

Comment: @Roflcoptr Yay!

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot more fake and plastic-like up close than I remember seeing in the movie.

Comment: Surely an Emperor would have an Imperial rather than Royal Guard.

Comment: Palpatine has guards at least in Revenge of the Sith too, but there they are dark purple-ish. Clearly the predecessor to the Royal Guard.

Comment: On closer look: First there were the Republic Senate Guardsman, then the Senate Guard (also known as the Blue Guard, which are the ones I'm referring to above), then the Red Guard which finally transformed into the Royal Guard.

Comment: I've always known them as the Emperor's Royal Guard. It's what they were called in the original Kenner figures. http://terrordaves.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/star_wars_figures.jpg

Comment: Didn't those people ever hear about it being BAD to be red-shirts?

Comment: Incidentally, I always thought these guys were insanely awesome as a kid, and imagined that Luke would have been in deep trouble if he ever ran up against them.

Comment: @SeanDuggan A shame that they never actually do anything. Ever.  In any of the movies.

Comment: @Zibbobz So true.... well, other then be taken out completely in like half a second by Yoda in RotS. That little green imp sneak-attacked from behind (shouldn't they have been guarding the door on the outside instead of facing inside the room??) - not very Jedi-like...

Comment: The helmets and robes look incredibly impractical in combat. Can the actors even turn their head while wearing those helmets?